# How do I add a color picker in Komodo?

Tags: color-picker, komodo

How do I add a color picker in Komodo? I need to have a color picker utility for Komodo, if I work in a css file I want to be able to pick colors for my background colors etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension at http://community.activestate.com/forum/color-picker-macro-useful-css. I don't know if it works ok but it seems to correspond to what you want

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should upgrade ... as Komodo **5.1.0** introduced the [color picker](http://trentm.com/blog/archives/2009/03/13/hyperlinks-in-komodo-510b1/) feature.

[image]